# Synge inequality

Tags: submanifold

Let $f : M \rightarrow N$ be an isometric immersion, and let $\gamma :[0,1] \rightarrow M$ be a smooth curve such that $f\circ\gamma $ is a geodesic in $N$ . Show that $ \gamma$ is a geodesic in M and, for each plane $ \sigma \subset  T_{\gamma (t)}M$ such that $\gamma  ^{'}(t) \in \sigma$, prove the Synge inequality $K(\sigma ) ≤ \tilde K(\sigma).$
I am very confused because the first part is very easy with the properties of $ f$,  but the Synge inequality i don't know how do it.
*Upgrade, i think that i have to use this result from the Gauss equation: 
For an isometric immersion between Riemannian manifolds $f : M^{n }\rightarrow N^{n+p}$, the Gauss equation says that the (sectional) extrinsic curvature of $M^{n}$ in $N^{n+p}$ at $x \in M^{n}$ for a plane $ \sigma \subset T_{x}M$, $Kf(\sigma ) := KM(\sigma )−KN(\sigma )$, is given by $Kf(\sigma ) = <a(X,X),a(Y,Y)> − ||a(X,Y)||^{2} $, where a is the second fundamental form of the immersion and ${X,Y}$ any orthonormal basis of $\sigma$.

Comment: I've edited because you apparently don't know how to do subscripts or superscripts. Please tell us what $K$ and $\tilde K$ are (although I'm pretty sure I know).

Comment: @TedShifrin Superscripts use ^ to raise them.  If they are more than one character, the superscript is enclosed in braces, so 2^4 and 2^{abc} give $2^4$ and $2^{abc}$.  For subscripts, use the underline _

Comment: sorry, I do it with my cell phone and I forgot some commands, $ K (\sigma )$ in M  is the sectional curvature the same for the other $K$